# MySQL GROUP BY two columns

Tags: mysql

I attempting to firstly get users highest score of each individual level, then add up each of those scores to find the user's overall highscore.

```
+-----------+----------+----------+--------------------+
| id        | name     | score    | level_id           |
+-----------+----------+----------+--------------------+
|         1 | Jane Doe | 100      |                  1 | 
|         2 | Jane Doe | 50       |                  2 | 
|         1 | John Doe | 100      |                  1 |
|         2 | John Doe | 50       |                  2 |
+-----------+----------+----------+--------------------+
```

I've managed to find the user's highest score over all levels, but how can I do this for each level

```
select user_id, id, max(correct_answers)
from score
group by user_id
```

Comment: This is something of a faq but if you're going to persist with it, at least provide a sqlfiddle (and/or DDL equivalent), together WITH the desired result.

Comment: Can you post results what exactly you want from example table. Its little bit difficult to understand the requirement.

Comment: is there user_id's are not repeated? if it is not repeated then why your doing GROUP BY on user_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
   select user_id, max(correct_answers) maxs ,level_id
   from score
   group  by level_id,user_id
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d26cb/8)

Answer (score 0):

add level_id in group by too

```
select user_id, id, max(correct_answers)
from score group by user_id,level_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

select name, id, max(score)
from score
group by level_id,id